# Parsing table data from a websites source, using PHP query. Getting error at the function

Tags: php, dom, html-table

**CHANGED POST TO PHP QUERY FROM DOM!**

I'm trying to pull some information from a website to put it into a table, then print it in PHP.

I'm using the DOM parser as it looks like its exactly what I need.

```
<?php

 include 'phpQuery.php';


 $file = "http://evolve.sg-community.de/index.php?page=plugins";
 phpQuery::newDocumentFileHTML($file);

 $rowData = array();  


 pq("table tr td")->each(function($i) { 
 $rowData[] = pq($i)->html();
 });
 echo "<pre>";
 print_r($rowData);
 echo "</pre>";

 ?>
```

I keep getting:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION, expecting ')' in stuff on line 12
>   at

```
 pq("table tr td")->each(function($i) {
```

Comment: try `var_dump($table)` to find out what `$table` is?

Comment: What the error means is that the `$table` variable isn't an object (which means you can't call member functions since there aren't any) but rather something else, try running `var_dump($table)` to see what it is and go from there.

Comment: There you have it, it didn't find any results in the first place would be my first guess. Are you sure there's a element called/with the id `#theTable`? I checked the site in your code and it doesn't seem to have that id anywhere.

Comment: sorry it was supposed to be <table

Comment: changed it to that, and now its just doing nothing

Comment: what about $html->find('#theTable')->children()? this will return you child elements array..

Comment: Are you sure you can do `$html->find('<table')`? Since it's a DOM lib i'm guessing your best bet would be `$html->find('table')` instead?

Comment: i cant seem to get it to return it as table either, its just loading and loading

Comment: Perhaps the html is malformed and the DOM-parser hangs at some stage? I dunno really, check the documentation for info on what happens if it's bad HTML.

Comment: i changed table to tr and it now has outputs array(54)

Comment: and now my host went down for maintance, lol. go figure, right when i get it to show some data

Comment: When they come up again you'll have to loop through that array and for each of the elements you can do your find thingie :)

Answer (score 0):

do it in a better way using [phpQuery](http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/):

```
$file = "http://evolve.sg-community.de/index.php?page=plugins";
phpQuery::newDocumentFileHTML($file);

$rowData = array();  
pq("#theTable tr td")->each(function($node) {
   $rowData[] = $node->nodeValue;
});
echo "<pre>";
print_r($rowData);
echo "</pre>";
```

An alternative way is this:

```
foreach(pq("table:first-child tr td") as $td) {
   echo "<br>".$td->nodeValue;
   // examples
   // $td->tagName;  
   // $td->childNodes; 
}
```

it seems phpquery returns DOM elements.

Comment: i will try this once my webhost comes back up, it was just table btw

Comment: spits out Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION, expecting ')' in stuff

Comment: just tested; it works fine in my 5.3.13 (internet) and 5.3.5 (locally), still testing..

Comment: according to [this](http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/wiki/Dependencies) page only dependency is PHP5; 5.2 recommended. The following works?  pq("#theTable")->attr("id");  If yes, then something has to do with the "each" of phpquery.. EDIT: did you forget the function's closure });

Comment: pq("table tr td")->each(function($i) { $rowData[] = pq($i)>html() });

Answer (score 0):

Yes, phpQuery is a better tool for web-scraping, really.
DOMDocument-parser doesn't work with non-valid HTML.